# Send token in header GET-method

Tags: angularjs, image, get, header, asp.net-web-api2

There is a site and a web api. All the files I receive from the web api server.

I have an ADFS OAUTH2 authorization on the site. 
And I need get the images from the web api with the auth token.

So now I do something like this:

```
<img src='webApiUrl/Photo/Id?token=token_value' alt />
```

But I have got a bug with token length. It is very long for some clients and I cannot control it. 
I can send the authorization header with the xhr request but I do not understand how to set the authorization header for the site which requests the resources from the html via src.

Can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have an HTTP request to the Web API you can use Angular Interceptors to put your token on the request header. Here I chose to demonstrate the Bearer authentication. Like this:

```
appName.config(["$httpProvider", ($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) => {
                $httpProvider.interceptors.push(<any>["$q", "$location",
                    ($q: ng.IQService, $location: ng.ILocationService) => {
                        return {

                     // config is the request data, including all its properties
                            'request': (config) => {

                               // Intercepting only the API requests
                                if (config.url.indexOf(apiServerUrl) >= 0) {

                               // Getting the token from local storage for example
                                    var token = localStorage.getItem("token"); 

                               // Placing the token in the right header                                        
                                   if (token)
                                     config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token; 
                                }
                                return config;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]);
            }]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i try this method, Interceptor doesn't handle browser's request only $http.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this would solve your problem: http://blog.jsgoupil.com/request-image-files-with-angular-2-and-an-bearer-access-token/

It involves registering a pipe so that you can use secure `src` attributes with your `img` tags.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)